# Не работают события onTouch, onScale на ScrollView

Tags: java, android, прокрутка, scale

Нужно перехватить событие onScale на ScrollView. Поставил точки останова на onTouchEvent и onScale.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return true;
}
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.
        SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Тыкаю за пределами ScrollView - точки останова срабатывают нормально. Внутри - нифига.
Если в xml меняю ScrollView на RelativeLayout - начинает нормально отлавливать событие.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/myTable"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="*">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text=" Text" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="0"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Почему скролл игнорит и как с этим бороться?

Comment: А вы пробовали установить слушатель событий на сам `ScrollView`?

Comment: так вы обрезали цепочку событий в onTouchEvent вернув true, в onScale уже ничего не придет

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов, сделал как вы оба сказали, всё заработало как надо. Спасибо.

Comment: @Style-7, сделал как вы оба сказали, всё заработало как надо. Спасибо.